# How to parse/manipulate string values in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, string

I have a csv dataset like this -

```
TABLE NAME IS A VERSION IS 1
TYPE IS CODE
TABLE IS UNSORTED
VALUES ARE ( 01 P 02 N 03 S 04 A )
SEARCH IS LINEAR
,
TABLE NAME IS B VERSION IS 1
TYPE IS CODE
TABLE IS SORTED
VALUES ARE ( 0A M 0B S 0A D 01 ' ' 04 N 05 P 07 T 08 K 09 E )
SEARCH IS LINEAR
```

I did some parsing. The code is as follows:

```
df_type_code = df[df["Type"]=="CODE"]
columns = ['Table Name', 'Value']
df_type_code = pd.DataFrame(df_type_code, columns=columns)

for index, row in df_type_code.iterrows():
    span = 2
    words = row.Value.split(" ")
    row.Value = [",".join(words[i:i+span]) for i in range(0, len(words), span)]
df_type_code['Index'] = df_type_code.index

df_temp = (pd.DataFrame({'Table Name': list(df_type_code['Table Name']),
                    'Value': list(df_type_code['Value']),
                       'Index': list(df_type_code['Index'])})
      .set_index(['Index', 'Table Name']))

temp = df_temp.explode('Value')
temp.reset_index(inplace=True, level=1)
df_new = temp[['Table Name', 'Value']]

df_final = pd.concat([df_new, df_new['Value'].str.split(',', expand=True)], axis=1)
df_final = df_final.drop(df_final.columns[[1]], axis=1)
df_final.columns = ['Table Name', '1st', '2nd']
df_final.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_final = df_final[['Table Name', '1st', '2nd']]
print(df_final)
```

So the final output is as follows:
[image: output]

Basically What I am trying to achieve is that, in values the 1st item and 2nd item are linked, so they should come in a single row.

Now I got a new data item in the dataset as follows:

```
TABLE NAME IS C VERSION IS 1
TYPE IS CODE
TABLE IS SORTED
VALUES ARE ( A '02 01' B '04 26' F '08 13' H '07 24' M '02 12' Q '06 04' S '08 02' )
SEARCH IS NONLINEAR
```

The above code treats A and '02 in a single row, 01' and B in 2nd row and so on.
The output in this case should be A and '02 01' in a single row, B and '04 26' in 2nd row like this. How do I fix for such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in the step of splitting the lines on spaces, here:

```python
words = row.Value.split(" ")
```

Because you split on spaces, the string `'02 01'` will be split into two `'02` and `01'`
To solve this problem, you can use the builtin module **shlex**:

```python
import shlex
...
#change this:
#words = row.Value.split(" ")
#to this:
words = shlex.split(row.Value, posix = False)
#(posix = False) to preserve the inner quotes
```